# Java Annotations: Changing Data using Anotations

Tags: java, annotations

Perhaps I am overreaching on the use of JAVA annotations, but can someone explain to me whether what I am trying to achieve is possible. If it is, please point me in the right direction.

I have a simple `emum` containing currencies that are to be used in my application.

```
public enum Currency{
        EURO, DOLLARS
    }
```

I want to persist an amount `BigDecimal` together with its associated currency. I want to be able to retrieve both whenever needed. I know I can change the amount to string and concatenate them but isn't there a smarter way to do it, perhaps using annotations?

Comment: Why not just an object?

Comment: @CraigR8806 could you please explain how I can use  an object

Comment: Okay, I added an answer to help you out.  If it answers your question, don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to my post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create an object named Money like so:

```
public class Money{
    private Currency currency;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    public Money(Currency currency, BigDecimal amount){
        this.currency = currency;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Currency getCurrencyType(){
        return currency;
    }
    public BigDecimal getAmount(){
        return amount;
    }
}
```

Then to create an object from this class, you would just write something like this:

```
 Money money = new Money(Currency.EURO, new BigDecimal("24322.21"));
```

And then you can retrieve the values for by calling the `get` functions:

```
 System.out.println(money.getAmount().toString() + " " + money.getCurrencyType());
```